# how to combine similar lines of code into one

Tags: excel

Hello and thank you for your time, I have this piece of code which is working perfectly, I just need to know two things:

1- Is there a way to combine all those into one line?
something like **If .Cells(K, "D").Value = "L" or "RF" or "F" or "Dewat*" Then**

2- How do I tell the if statement to search for "Dewat*", because of spelling mistakes, users might input dewatering, DEWATERING, Dewataring and so on.

> ```
> If .Cells(K, "D").Value = "DT" Then
>     J = J + 1
>     .Rows(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Trailers").Range("A" & J + 1)
>     .Rows(K).EntireRow.Delete
> End If
>
>     If .Cells(K, "D").Value = "L" Then
>     J = J + 1
>     .Rows(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Trailers").Range("A" & J + 1)
>     .Rows(K).EntireRow.Delete
> End If
>
>     If .Cells(K, "D").Value = "RF" Then
>     J = J + 1
>     .Rows(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Trailers").Range("A" & J + 1)
>     .Rows(K).EntireRow.Delete
> End If
>
>     If .Cells(K, "D").Value = "F" Then
>     J = J + 1
>     .Rows(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Trailers").Range("A" & J + 1)
>     .Rows(K).EntireRow.Delete
> End If
> ```

Comment: For question 2 its usual to convert the string to uppercase/lowercase before checking them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Case 1**

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    If .Cells(K, "D").Value = "DT" Or .Cells(K, "D").Value = "L" Or .Cells(K, "D").Value = "RF" Or .Cells(K, "D").Value = "F" Then
        J = J + 1
        .Rows(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Trailers").Range("A" & J + 1)
        .Rows(K).EntireRow.Delete
    End If

End Sub
```

**Case 2**

```
Option Explicit

Sub test1()

    Dim UserInput As String, SearchInString As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        UserInput = .Range("A2").Value
        SearchInString = .Range("E1").Value

        If InStr(1, UserInput, SearchInString, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then '<- Check if User Input appears in the search string & if the value is greater than 0 means that appears in the string
            MsgBox "Appears"
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this works...

```
If ((.Cells(K, "D").Value = "DT") Or (.Cells(K, "D").Value = "L") Or (.Cells(K, "D").Value = "RF") Or (.Cells(K, "D").Value = "F")) Then
    J = J + 1
    .Rows(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Trailers").Range("A" & J + 1)
    .Rows(K).EntireRow.Delete
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for this, can I also add these in the middle:    .Cells(K, "D").Value = "Dewa*",  .Cells(K, "D").Value = "DEWA*",  .Cells(K, "D").Value = "dewa*",     and so on? so that I don't need to mess with the uppercase/lowercase conversion.

Comment: It's giving me a syntax error, I don't know how to attach a screen shot here, I'll do it above.

Comment: This is why I said "perhaps"... If your code is VB than the or notation is different: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/or-operator. I correct the answer.

Comment: Forgive me to bother you again like this but I can't get the * to work, this is the line I'm using:        If ((.Cells(K, "E").Value = "HFMO*")) Then

Comment: If ((.Cells(K, "E").Value Like "HFMO*"))

Comment: Thank you again nologin, you truly helped me from the start, that particular line did not work, I just fooled around with your example and eventualy this one worked ....

Comment: If .Cells(K, "E").Value Like "HFMWO*" Then